# GAE Python Javascript: How to insert response data from facebook login into the datastore?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, facebook-login

So I finished linking the facebook login using the javascript sdk.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '{{facebook_app_id}}',
        channelUrl : '//localhost:8097/channel.html',
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // connected
        alert(response.authResponse.userID);
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                  var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                  userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' + response.name;
                alert(response.name);
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(userInfo);
                });
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
        alert("not_authorized");
      } else {
        // not_logged_in
        alert("not_logged_in");
      }
     });

    FB.Event.subscribe('{% if current_user %}auth.logout{% else %}auth.login{% endif %}', function(response) {
      {% if current_user %} window.location = "/logout" {% else %} window.location.reload(); {% endif %}
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

So,

How do you use javascript to pass arguments and insert data to the datastore securely. Example, Response.name.  Also in the facebook login. I realize they uses a token for the login response and it is also in their python facebook example datastore. However I created my own  login system, so I don't think I needed to use that token at all. Are there any risk for not using that token at all?

Answer (score 2):

Doing it with pure JavaScript is a bit harder, but you could use jQuery and more specifically the [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). So by having the `id` and the `name` you could simply send this information back to your application like this:

```
$.post("/login/facebook/", { id: response.id, name: response.name })
.done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

On the backend side you should have a handler that would expect this kind kind of request in order to login that Facebook user.

The only problem as you can see here by doing that, is that anybody could make this POST request with any ID and Name and you wouldn't know if they actually real users or just trying to get into your system. That's why Facebook is using the access token, so you can send it back to your server and by using the `token`, the `App ID` and the `App Secret` you are able to retrieve the actual user.

On the next step, since you implemented your own login system, you should use session cookies to store the information regarding the currently logged in user, so you would be able to navigate through the site. Even though it's very doable to do it on your own, I would suggest you using some kind of framework that helps you with all that.

When we had a similar situation, after some research we concluded on using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) because of the [Sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions) and later we found out that connecting Facebook wasn't that hard by using the the [Flask-OAuth](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/) extension.

You can find a complete example using Flask, Sessions, Facebook Login and bunch of other things on one of my open source projects called [gae-init](https://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init/src).